# Referencing class variables in other class variables

Tags: php, class

I have the following in a class.

```
class My_Class {
    $x = 'happy';
    $y = array( 'iam' => $this->x);
    //getting a 500 error with that.
    function __construct() {
        // scripts, etc
    }
}
```

I get an unexpected $this (T_VARIABLE). Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your full code. Either (A) You're not in scope of $this, or (B) You're in a static method

Comment: it looks like ur missing a semicolon..

Comment: hmm thats weird .. it must be a php bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use $this when defining the instance variables. Try this alternative:

```
class My_Class {
    var $x = 'happy';
    var $y = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->y['iam'] = $this->x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a variable in the class definition. Constants work, but anything else (concatenation, etc) will throw an error.